# Re-order ul list on click with jquery?

Tags: jquery, list, sorting, html-lists

I'd like to know how to do this can be accomplished

I have a ul list that I'd like to re-sort to a unique order, when clicking on another div, with jQuery.

```
<ul id="list">
   <li id="1"></li>
   <li id="2"></li>
   <li id="3"></li>
   <li id="4"></li>
</ul>

<div class="click-to-sort"></div>
```

I've attempted this function to try and change #2 to the 3rd child of the list for example, but no luck.

```
$('.click-to-sort').click(function(){        
    $('#2').prependTo($('#list li:eq(3)'));
});
```

Comment: No one is doing your project for you. Do you it come back if you are stuck in something. before this OP gets down voted to oblivion

Comment: I've edited the post to include more of what I've attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to order the list in different ways using a combination of .after and .before, for example:

```
$('.click-to-sort').click(function(){  
     $('1').after($("2"));
     $('3').before($("1"));
});
```

There are more sensible solutions I'm sure, but this works.